# My friend cannot... Or My friend will not able

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to say.
My friend told me that He  will not be able to visit us next month. 
Or I have to say. 
My friend told me  that He cannot visit us next month.

Comment: also: My friend told me that he wouldn't be able to / couldn't visit us next month.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, and I don't find any difference in meaning.

The present simple is often used with future meaning.